# How to deal with Users who are misguiding Question Poster with wrong answers using comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

I have come across some users who are posting comments which will lead to multiple issues. For Example in this [Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106846/my-site-crashed) there is a comment which suggests to delete some modules if site has issue with php memory setting.. which is absolutely wrong way to proceed..

I don't think flagging comment is a best option since none of the criteria makes sense.. Is there any other way to deal with such users who are doing same mistakes again and again ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write a comment saying that the previous comment is wrong, eventually explaining why.

Including the ones for answers, none of the flags is about the correctness of the commnet/answer; Moderators don't judge that. For answers, the correctness is expressed by other users with voting; for comments, there is no way to vote for them.

Wrong comments, like wrong answers, have a purpose: They let you say nobody should do as the comment/answer says.